# How to use document in a for loop in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I'm trying to write a "for" loop that will print out the properties associated with the "document" object (write, getElementById, etc.) on an HTML page.  Not for anything practical, just for learning purposes.  If use the "document" object directly, it works fine, but if I try to use a variable that has the value "document" it won't work.  Here's the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function objProps() {
                var myObj=prompt("Object?");
                    for (x in myObj) {
                        document.write(x + "<br />");
                    }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="objProps()">Click me to see the properties of an object</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I type "document" in the prompt, I just get numeric values, but if I change the code in the for loop from "myObj" to "document" it works just as intended.

Any help greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the other answers, you probably really don't want to use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) since it will overwrite everything on the page.

Comment: thanks @MattBurland, that's a good point.  I wouldn't use it on a page with other content, but right now I'm just trying to get this function working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I type "document" in the prompt, I just get numeric values

That's because you're using `for-in` on a **string**. The return value of the `prompt` will be the string `"document"`, not the document object.

If you want to use a string name to look up a global property (`document` is a global property), you can do that via the `window` global, which is a reference to the global object:

```
for (x in window[myObj])
```

That only works for globals, and only for globals that are global properties (as of ES2015, not all globals become properties of the global object).

It's also worth noting that `for-in` only visits *enumerable* properties. I don't think there's any spec for whether the various properties of `document` are required to be enumerable, so your results may vary from browser to browser.

---

Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(disclosure: link to my anemic little blog)*. Remember to declare your variables.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I didn't know about the global object, just checked it out on your page.  Good info, now I know more about it.

Answer (score 2):

The string `"document"` is not equal to the global variable `document`.  If you're trying to access global variables using the name of the variable, you can use bracket notation:

```js
    function objProps() {
        // var myObj=prompt("Object?");
        var myObj='document';
        for (x in window[myObj]) {
            document.write(x + "<br />");
        }
    }
    objProps();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [] nomenclature for using the prompt:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Title</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function objProps() {
                    var str = prompt("Object?");
                    var myObj=window[str];
                        for (x in myObj) {
                            document.write(x + "<br />");
                        }
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <button onclick="objProps()">Click me to see the properties of an object</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```